# Custom Tileset won't appear on Android - mapboxsdk

Tags: kotlin, maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have created a custom tile on mapbox studio and it is visible correctly on the studio but when I use that tile ID in my kotlin code using the Vector source, it does not show, although the logcat shows the request is successful. The tileset I created is also set to public. Even though I've tried loading the built in tile of mapbox "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2" which is taken from the github repository of mapbox [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/blob/7e6c94892f063c1bee878bfac84043f9162e10ad/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/maps/testapp/examples/VectorTileSourceActivity.kt). This one shown below is also not visible on android although it is visible on mapbox studio.

```
                    style.addSource(
                        VectorSource("terrain-data", "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2")
                    )


                    style.addLayer(
                        LineLayer("terrain-layer", "terrain-data")
                            .withProperties(
                                PropertyFactory.lineJoin(Property.LINE_JOIN_ROUND),
                                PropertyFactory.lineCap(Property.LINE_CAP_ROUND),
                                PropertyFactory.lineColor(Color.parseColor("#ff69b4")),
                                PropertyFactory.lineWidth(1.9f)
                        )
                    )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after adding the name of source layer (that can be found on the top left corner, when you open the custom tileset), like below:

[Custom Tileset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzomZ.png)

`LineLayer("terrain-layer", "terrain-data").withSourceLayer("name_of_source_layer")`